# library importing error while importing Microsoft sync framework toolkit source to workspace

Tags: android, eclipse, synchronization, microsoft-sync-framework

I need to sync my android application DB with Microsoft SQL Server with Microsoft SYNC framework toolkit. 
I download it from [here](http://selvinlistsyncsample.codeplex.com/).

as per documentation I download the source code and import the library projects with these steps:-

1. Download source and put it to Myworkspace.
2. Download ActionBarSherlock, unzip and create new project(ActionBarSherlock)
   from "library" folder.
3. Import both projects(from library and sample folder) to Eclipse.

But library project have an error sign and in console its showing as

```
[2013-10-31 13:57:44 - SyncFramework] ERROR: resource directory 'C:\Users\Dell\Downloads\selvinlistsyncsample-900c1ee67eb9\selvinlistsyncsample_900c1ee67eb9\library\res' does not exist
```

as library project does not have any res folder. 
please help me for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also face same problem.
do these following step to solve it:-

1. copy all three package from source folder and put it into your application src folder.
2. copy jackson-mini-1.9.10.jar from /SyncFramework/libs folder and put this .jar into your application /libs folder
3. right click on .jar and add this to build path.
4. press ctrl+shift+o if you have any error in your source files.

that's it. Now you can play with it.